# Can I have optional trait bounds?

Tags: generics, rust

Given a trait that models a conditional probability distribution:

```
trait Distribution {
    type T;
    fn sample<U>(&self, x: U) -> Self::T;
}
```

I want to implement the trait for two structs, `ConditionalNormal` and `MultivariateConditionalNormal` which model a scalar and vector valued distribution respectively.

Such implementations look like this:

```
struct ConditionalNormal;

impl Distribution for ConditionalNormal {
    type T = f64;

    fn sample<U>(&self, x: U) -> Self::T {
        0.0
    }
}

struct MultivariateConditionalNormal;

impl Distribution for MultivariateConditionalNormal {
    type T = f64;

    fn sample<U>(&self, x: U) -> Self::T {
        0.0 + x[0]
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=14c0cdc19c2c4cbaa10d101de66765f9&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

However, the implementation for `MultivariateConditionalNormal` is invalid because the generic `x[0]` is not indexable.
If I add the trait bounds `std::ops::Index<usize>` the implementation for `ConditionalNormal` is invalid, because a scalar `f64` is not indexable.

I have heard that e.g. the `Sized` trait accepts optional trait bounds via `?Sized`; can I do something similar? Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the definition of the trait to

```
trait Distribution<U> {
    type T;
    fn sample(&self, x: U) -> Self::T;
}
```

This allows you to implement it on various types with different trait bounds.

```
impl<U> Distribution<U> for ConditionalNormal {
    // ...
}

impl<U> Distribution<U> for MultivariateConditionalNormal
where
    U: std::ops::Index<usize, Output = f64>,
{
    // ...
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d52648c2a93e7cb89dd70d809e93232f&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can add a new trait to specify what are the capabilities of `U`:

```
trait Distribution {
    type T;
    fn sample<U>(&self, x: U) -> Self::T
    where
        U: Samplable;
}

struct ConditionalNormal;

impl Distribution for ConditionalNormal {
    type T = f64;

    fn sample<U>(&self, x: U) -> Self::T
    where
        U: Samplable,
    {
        0.0.value()
    }
}

struct MultivariateConditionalNormal;

impl Distribution for MultivariateConditionalNormal {
    type T = f64;

    fn sample<U>(&self, x: U) -> Self::T
    where
        U: Samplable,
    {
        0.0 + x.value()
    }
}

trait Samplable {
    fn value(&self) -> f64;
}

impl Samplable for f64 {
    fn value(&self) -> f64 {
        *self
    }
}

impl Samplable for Vec<f64> {
    fn value(&self) -> f64 {
        self[0]
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: I like this solution as well! Might try it in the future! Thanks!

Comment: @TheodorJohnson You must put more semantic in your generics. When you have a generic type `T`, put yourself the question: *what will I do with `T`?* and put those operations as methods of a new trait.